# add checkbox in JTable

Tags: java, swing

I read other posts on the same topic, but i didn't get what i exactly wanted.
Can anyone tellhow can i add checkbox in JTable in the Raw named "selectionné"

```js
       int linenumber=0;
         JFileChooser filechooser=new JFileChooser();
        int aa=filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        ///--------------------------------------------
        String col[]={"Les Requéte","selectionné"};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new      DefaultTableModel(null,col);
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        ///-------------
     
      if (aa== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try {  
                 file= filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                 in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file-));
                 String line = null;
               while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            linenumber++; tableModel.addRow(line.split(", "));      
                }
     filereader.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was your approach to implementing one and the result?

Comment: Please search in SO or Google, this is already answered.

Comment: `I read other posts on the same topic, but i didn't get what i exactly wanted`  - Well link to the posts you read. We can't guess what you have tried and don't want to spend time repeating the same suggestion. And you will never get "exactly" what your wanted. The idea is for you to understand the suggestions and customize the code for your exact requirement. Ask specific questions about the code you find if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
linenumber++; tableModel.addRow(line.split(", "));
```

That line of code is attempting to add multiple Strings to the TableModel. If you want a checkbox then you need to add a String and a Boolean.

Then when you create the TableModel you need to override the getColumnClass() method so the table can use the appropriate renderer/editor.

So when you create the model you need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, )
    {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            return column == 0 ? String.class : Boolean.class;
        }
    };
```

When you add data to the table your code needs to be something like:

```
Object[] row = {"someText", Boolean.FALSE};
model.addRow( row );
```

So you will need to parse the data to find out what value to use for your Boolean (TRUE or FALSE).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own table model. The DefaultTableModel does not seem to render booleans as checkboxes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Editable Color Table");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    Object rowData[][] = { { "1", Boolean.TRUE }, { "2", Boolean.TRUE }, { "3", Boolean.FALSE },
            { "4", Boolean.TRUE }, { "5", Boolean.FALSE }, };

    String columnNames[] = {"Les Requéte","selectionné"};

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowData.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return rowData[row][column];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        rowData[row][column] = value;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return (column != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: but there is no need to extend the AbstractTableModel. Just extend the DefaultTableModel and override the `getColumnClass(...)` method. Then you can just use the `addRow(...)` method of the

Comment: @camickr absolutly!

Answer (score 0):

```js
int linenumber=0;
         JFileChooser filechooser=new JFileChooser();
        int aa=filechooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        ///--------------------------------------------
        String col[]={"Les Requéte","selectionné"};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new      DefaultTableModel()
        {
          public Class getColumnClass(int column){
            return column == 0?String.class :Boolean.class;
            }
        };
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
        table.setModel(tableModel);
Object [] row={Bookean.FALSE};
        ///-------------
     
      if (aa== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try {  
                 file= filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                 in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file-));
                 String line = null;
               while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    linenumber++; 
                   tableModel.addRow(line.split(", "));
                   tableModel.addRow(row):
                   
                }
     filereader.close();
```